# DispatchSourceTimer crashes in deinit/dealloc

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use a DispatchSourceTimer to run a repeating timer on another thread. This code runs fine in a playground, however in my iOS app it keeps crashing either on the deinit method (or if I remove the deinit it crashes on dealloc for the thread its running on) and I can't figure out why. Is there a better way to use DispatchSourceTimer?

```swift
import UIKit

class DispatchTest {
    var timer: DispatchSourceTimer
    var count: Int = 0
    init(timeInterval: TimeInterval) {
        timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(flags: .strict, queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default))
        timer.schedule(deadline: .now() + timeInterval, repeating: timeInterval, leeway: .milliseconds(100))
    }

    func startTimer() {
        timer.setEventHandler(handler: {[weak self] in
            self?.count += 1
            if let count = self?.count {
                print(count)
            }
            
        })
        timer.resume()
    }
    
    deinit {
        timer.setEventHandler {}
        timer.cancel()
    }
    
    func stopTimer() {
        self.timer.cancel()
    }
}

let dispatch = DispatchTest(timeInterval: 1)
dispatch.startTimer()
```

Comment: I rand your code in a test project and didn't have any issues. You might want to share where and how you are using the timer. Also, please share any debug output or stack traces you might see.

Comment: Perhaps a similar problem at https://stackoverflow.com/q/65056961/5922621 , XCTest hangs after reference in deinit.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem. After digging around I have found the answer in Apple's Dispatch documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452801-dispatch_suspend :

> It is a programmer error to release an object that is currently suspended, because suspension implies that there is still work to be done. Therefore, always balance calls to this method with a corresponding call to dispatch_resume before disposing of the object. The behavior when releasing the last reference to a dispatch object while it is in a suspended state is undefined.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452929-dispatch_resume :

> New dispatch event source objects returned by dispatch_source_create have a suspension count of 1

What I have deduced from this is that all new DispatchSource objects start suspended and thus the crash happens if you have not resumed the timer before deallocation.

The solution is to make sure the timer is in a resumed state before it is released.